# JQuery Function not be invoked through Javascript in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html5-video

It works perfect in all major browsers, but not in IE7.

The Java script code is:

```
$(function() {
var $hdVid = jQuery.noConflict();
$hdVid(function() {
    $hdVid('.hd-flv-player').hdVideo();
});
});
```

JQuery is:

```
(function($) {

// plugin definition
$.fn.hdVideo = function(options) {
    // build main options before element iteration
    var defaults = {
        theme: 'simpledark',
        childtheme: ''
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    // iterate and reformat each matched element
    return this.each(function() {
        var $hdVideo = $(this);

        $hdVideo.removeAttr('controls');
        //create html structure
        //main wrapper

        var $video_wrap=$('<div id="hd-player"></div>');
        var $video_hd_html_player = $('<div id="hd_html_player"></div>').addClass('hd-video-player').addClass(options.theme).addClass(options.childtheme);
        //controls wraper
        var $video_controls = $('<div class="hd-video-main-control"></div><div class="hd-video-controls"><div class="hd-video-seek-container"><div class="hd-video-seek"></div></div><div class="hd-video-buffer-container"><div class="hd-video-buffer"></div></div><div class="hd-video-options cf"><a class="hd-video-play" title="Play/Pause"></a><div class="hd-video-timer"><span class="hd-video-timer-curr">00:00</span><span class="hd-video-sep">&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span><span class="hd-video-timer-tot-time">00:00</span></div><div class="hd-full-screen"><a class="hd-full-screen-button" title="Normal/FullScreen"></a></div><div class="hd-volume-box"><div class="hd-volume-slider-container"><div class="hd-volume-slider"></div></div><a class="hd-volume-button" title="Mute/Unmute"></a><div class="hd-volume-value-slider"></div></div><div class="hd-hd-swipe"><a class="hd-hd-swipe-button" title="High Definition / Low Definition"></a></div><div class="hd-flv-html5-switch"><a title="Switch to Flash"></a></div></div></div>');
        $video_wrap.append($video_hd_html_player);
        $hdVideo.wrap($video_wrap);
        $hdVideo.after($video_controls);
        var full_screen = 0;
        //get new elements
        var $video_container = $hdVideo.parent('.hd-video-player');
        var $video_main_control = $('.hd-video-main-control', $video_container);
        $video_controls = $('.hd-video-controls', $video_container);
        var $hd_play_btn = $('.hd-video-play', $video_container);
        var $hd_video_seek = $('.hd-video-seek', $video_container);
        var $hd_video_buffer = $('.hd-video-buffer', $video_container);
        var $hd_video_timer_curr = $('.hd-video-timer-curr', $video_container);
        var $hd_video_timer_tot_time = $('.hd-video-timer-tot-time', $video_container);
        var $hd_volume = $('.hd-volume-slider', $video_container);
        var $hd_volume_value = $('.hd-volume-value-slider', $video_container);
        var $hd_volume_btn = $('.hd-volume-button', $video_container);
        var $hd_hd_swipe_btn = $('.hd-hd-swipe-button', $video_container);
        var $hd_full_screen_btn = $('.hd-full-screen-button', $video_container);
        var $player_change_btn = $('.hd-flv-html5-switch', $video_container);
        $video_controls.hide(); // keep the controls hidden
        var firstTime=1;

        /* Video Elements Fetching */
        var videoAttr = {};
        videoAttr.poster = $("video").attr("poster");
        videoAttr.src = $("source").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("src");
        });
        videoAttr.quality = $("source").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("data-quality");
        });
        videoAttr.type = $("source").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("type");
        });
        videoAttr.codecs = $("source").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("codecs");
        });

        /* Video Elements Fetching Ends */

        /* Poster image into screen image */

        var $video_bind_pst = $('<img class="hd-vid-poster-img" src="'+videoAttr.poster+'" data-width="544" data-height="306"><div class="hd-video-main-control"></div>');
        //$hdVideo.before($video_bind_pst);

        //var
        //width: 630px !important; height: 354px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; max-width: 630px !important;

        /* Poster image into screen image ends*/

        /* Play/Pause */
        var gPlay = function() {

            txt =  navigator.platform ;
            if(txt =='iPhone'|| txt =='Linux armv7l')
            {
                window.location.href = videoAttr.src[0];
            }
            else{
                if($hdVideo.attr('paused') == false) {
                    $hdVideo[0].pause();
                    $video_main_control.removeClass("hd-video-main-control-none");
                }
                else {
                    if(firstTime)
                    {
                        $hdVideo.attr('src', vidStatistics.default_vid_src);
                        firstTime=0;
                    }
                    $hdVideo[0].play();
                    $hdVideo.attr('preload', 'auto');
                    $video_main_control.addClass("hd-video-main-control-none");
                    $hdVideo.addClass("video1-visible");
                }
            }
            return false;
        };

        var hd_autoply =$("video").attr("play_auto");
        if(hd_autoply=="autoplay"){
            $hdVideo[0].play();
            $video_main_control.addClass("hd-video-main-control-none");
            $hd_play_btn.addClass('hd-paused-button');
        }

        $video_main_control.click(gPlay);
        $hd_play_btn.click(gPlay);
        $hdVideo.click(gPlay);
        $hdVideo.bind('play', function() {
            $hd_play_btn.addClass('hd-paused-button');
            return false;
        });
        $hdVideo.bind('pause', function() {
            $hd_play_btn.removeClass('hd-paused-button');
            return false;
        });
        $hdVideo.bind('ended', function() {
            $hd_play_btn.removeClass('hd-paused-button');
            $(".hd-video-main-control").removeClass('hd-video-main-control-none');
            return false;
        });

        var gTimeFormat=function(seconds){
            var m=Math.floor(seconds/60)<10?"0"+Math.floor(seconds/60):Math.floor(seconds/60);
            var s=Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10?"0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)):Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
            return m+":"+s;
        };
        /* Play/Pause */

        /* Progressbar Slider */
        var seeksliding;
        var createSeek = function() {
            if($hdVideo.attr('readyState'))
            {
                $hd_video_timer_tot_time.text(gTimeFormat($hdVideo.attr('duration')));
                var video_duration = $hdVideo.attr('duration');
                $hd_video_seek.slider({
                    value: 0,
                    step: 0.01,
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    range: "min",
                    max: video_duration,
                    animate: true,
                    slide: function(){
                        seeksliding = true;
                    },
                    stop:function(e,ui){
                        seeksliding = false;
                        $hdVideo.attr("currentTime",ui.value);
                    }
                });
                $video_controls.show();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(createSeek, 150);
            }
            return false;
        };
        createSeek();

        var seekUpdate = function() {
            var currenttime = $hdVideo.attr('currentTime');
            if(!seeksliding)
            {
                $hd_video_seek.slider('value', currenttime);
                $hd_video_timer_curr.text(gTimeFormat(currenttime));
            }
            return false;
        };
        $hdVideo.bind('timeupdate', seekUpdate);
        /* Progressbar Slider */

        /* Buffer Slider */
        var buffersliding;
        var createBuffer = function() {
            if($hdVideo.attr('readyState'))
            {
                $hd_video_timer_tot_time.text(gTimeFormat($hdVideo.attr('duration')));
                var video_duration = $hdVideo.attr('duration');
                $hd_video_buffer.slider({
                    value: 0,
                    step: 0.01,
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    range: "min",
                    max: video_duration,
                    animate: true,
                    disabled: true,
                    slide: function(){
                        buffersliding = true;
                    },
                    stop:function(e,ui){
                        buffersliding = false;
                        $hdVideo.attr("buffered",ui.value).end(0);
                    }
                });
                $video_controls.show();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(createBuffer, 150);
            }
            return false;
        };
        createBuffer();

//              var buffertime = $hdVideo.get(0).buffered.end(0);
            var buffertime = $hdVideo[0].buffered.end(0);
            var currenttime = $hdVideo.attr('currentTime');
            if(!buffersliding)
            {
                if(currenttime>buffertime){
                    $hd_video_buffer.slider('value', currenttime);
                }
                else{
                    $hd_video_buffer.slider('value', buffertime);
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        $hdVideo.bind('timeupdate', bufferUpdate);
        /* Buffer Slider end*/

        /* Volume Control */
        var video_volume = 1;
        $hd_volume.slider({
            value: 0.4,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            max: 1,
            step: 0.05,
            animate: true,
            slide:function(e,ui){
                $hdVideo.attr('muted',false);
                video_volume = ui.value;
                $hdVideo.attr('volume',ui.value);
                $hd_volume_btn.removeClass('hd-volume-mute');

                if(ui.value*100 == 0) {
                    $hd_volume_btn.css('background-position', '-244px -126px');
                }
                else if(ui.value*100 <= 15) {
                    $hd_volume_btn.css('background-position', '-244px -96px');
                }
                else if (ui.value*100 <= 45) {
                    $hd_volume_btn.css('background-position', '-244px -66px');
                }
                else if (ui.value*100 <= 85) {
                    $hd_volume_btn.css('background-position', '-244px -36px');
                }
                else {
                    $hd_volume_btn.css('background-position', '-244px -6px');
                }
            }
        });

        var muteVolume = function() {
            if($hdVideo.attr('muted')==true) {
                $hdVideo.attr('muted', false);
                $hd_volume.slider('value', video_volume);
                $hd_volume_btn.removeClass('hd-volume-mute');
            }else{
                $hdVideo.attr('muted', true);
                $hd_volume.slider('value', '0');
                $hd_volume_btn.addClass('hd-volume-mute');
            }
            return false;
        };
        /* Volume Control */
        /* Full Screen */
        var fullScreen = function(){
            if(full_screen == 0){
                full_screen = 1;
                $(".hd-video-player").addClass("fullscreen-video-container");
                $(".hd-video-player video.hd-flv-player").addClass("fullscreen-video");
                $(".hd-video-main-control").addClass("fullscreen-hd-video-main-control");
                $(".hd-video-controls").addClass("fullscreen-control-elements");
            }
            else
            {
                full_screen = 0;
                $(".hd-video-player").removeClass("fullscreen-video-container");
                $(".hd-video-player video.hd-flv-player").removeClass("fullscreen-video");
                $(".hd-video-main-control").removeClass("fullscreen-hd-video-main-control");
                $(".hd-video-controls").removeClass("fullscreen-control-elements");
            }
            return false;
        };
        $('body').keydown(function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 27 && full_screen == 1) {
                fullScreen();
            }
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        });
        /* Full Screen Ends*/

        /* Default Video Quality */
        var defaultVideoQuality = function(videoAttr){
            var vidStatistics = {};
            vidStatistics.support_vid_count=0;
            var i, isSupp, myVid=document.createElement('video');
            for(i=videoAttr.quality.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                path = videoAttr.src[i];
                var path = videoAttr.src[i],
                ext = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                isSupp = myVid.canPlayType('video/'+ext+';');
                if(isSupp=="maybe" || isSupp=="probably" )
                {
                    vidStatistics.default_vid_qty = videoAttr.quality[i];
                    vidStatistics.default_vid_src = videoAttr.src[i];
                    vidStatistics.support_vid_count++;
                }
            }
            if(vidStatistics.default_vid_qty == "hd")
                $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").addClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
            else
                $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").removeClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");

            return(vidStatistics);
        };
        /* Default Video Quality Ends*/

        /* HD Available Check */
        var hdAvailableCheck = function(videoAttr){
            var k=0, i, isSupp, sdSupport = 0;
            var  myVid=document.createElement('video');
            for(i=0; i<videoAttr.quality.length; i++)
            {
                path = videoAttr.src[i];
                var path = videoAttr.src[i],
                ext = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                isSupp = myVid.canPlayType('video/'+ext+';');
                if(isSupp=="maybe" || isSupp=="probably" )
                {
                    if(videoAttr.quality[i]=="hd")
                        k=1;
                    else
                        sdSupport=1;
                }
            }
            if (k==0)
                $hd_hd_swipe_btn.css('display', 'none');
            if (sdSupport==0)
                $hd_hd_swipe_btn.css('pointer-events', 'none').css('cursor', 'default');
            return false;
        }
        /* HD Available Check Ends*/

        /* Video Quality Check*/
        var videoQualityCheck = function(){
            var i, $currVid, currQuality;
            $currVid = $hdVideo[0].currentSrc;
            for(i=0; i<videoAttr.quality.length; i++) //Get current video quality
                if($currVid == videoAttr.src[i])
                    currQuality=videoAttr.quality[i];
            if(currQuality == "hd")
                $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").addClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
            else
                $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").removeClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
            return false;
        }
        /* Video Quality Check Ends*/

        /* Quality Swipe */
        var playerstage = 0;
        var hdswipe = function(){
            var currVid, currExt, currVidName, currQuality, i;
            if($hdVideo.attr('paused')==false)
                playerstage=1;
            currVid = $hdVideo[0].currentSrc;
            var currVidTime = $hdVideo.attr('currentTime');
            currExt = currVid.substr(currVid.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            for(i=0; i<videoAttr.quality.length; i++) //Get current video quality
                if(currVid == videoAttr.src[i])
                    currQuality=videoAttr.quality[i];
            for(i=0; i<videoAttr.quality.length; i++) //Swipe the Video
            {
                if((currExt==videoAttr.src[i].substr(videoAttr.src[i].lastIndexOf('.') + 1))&&(currQuality!= videoAttr.quality[i]))
                {  
                    $hdVideo.attr('src', videoAttr.src[i]);
                    resumeCurrTime(currVidTime);
                    gPlay();
                    createSeek();
                    createBuffer();
                    playerstage=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            alert(currQuality);
            if(currQuality == "sd")
                $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").addClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
            else
                $("a.hd-hd-swipe-button").removeClass("hd-hd-swipe-button-hd");
            return false;
        }

        var resumeCurrTime = function(currVidTime) {
            if($hdVideo.attr('readyState'))
            {
                $hdVideo[0].currentTime = currVidTime;
            }
            else                            
                setTimeout(function() { resumeCurrTime(currVidTime); }, 150);
            return false;
        }
        /* Quality Swipe Ends */

        /* HTML5 / FLV Swipe */
        var playerChangeIntFn = function(){
            if(full_screen==1)
                fullScreen();
            $hdVideo.attr('preload', 'none');
            $hdVideo.load();
            var trigger = "flash";
            playerChange(trigger);
            return false;
        };
        /* HTML5 / FLV Swipe Ends */
        var vidStatistics = {};
        vidStatistics = defaultVideoQuality(videoAttr);
        hdAvailableCheck(videoAttr);
        $hd_hd_swipe_btn.click(hdswipe); //HD On/Off
        $hd_volume_btn.click(muteVolume); //Mute Volume
        $hd_full_screen_btn.click(fullScreen); //Full Screen On/Off
        $video_container.dblclick(fullScreen); //Full Screen On/Off
        $player_change_btn.click(playerChangeIntFn); //Full Screen On/Off
    });
};
// plugin defaults
$.fn.hdVideo.defaults = {
};
})(jQuery);
```

HTML is:

```
<video src="" width="830" height="354" class="hd-flv-player" poster="asserts/poster.png" controls="controls" data-name="demo video" data-uid="57fb2708" preload="none">
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" data-quality="hd"></source>
        <source src="http://static.clipcanvas.com/sample/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4" data-quality="sd"></source>
        <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" data-quality="hd"></source>
        <source src="asserts/300_VP8.webm" data-quality="sd"></source>
    </video>
```

Doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Note: I know that IE7 wont support HTML5 Video. But I just want the control code should be binded. So that I can use Flash Fall back.

Comment: This the only Error I got, @Jan:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Timestamp: Thu, 25 Oct 2012 05:14:51 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 319
Char: 21
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/hd-videos/version1.0.f/scripts/hd-video.js

Comment: Apparently there's an error in `hd-video.js` at line 319. Without seeing the code there's no telling what it is.

Comment: That error is because of ie7 support for "myVid.canPlayType()" in JQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply to your comment

> That error is because of ie7 support for "myVid.canPlayType()" in
>   JQuery

Then that needs to be fixed, no? Even though it looks like a third-party library, you can still fix code in them, and even submit bug fixes to the developer. Maybe they even have a later version of the library out, you could check.

```
if (myVid.canPlayType)
```

will check for the existence of the function in the object. If it doesn't exist, like you said it probably doesn't support HTML video. You should then exit the plugin with an error, or have an option in the plugin which content should be used as a fallback.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6nHnw/1/)

Comment: This lead to problem with other browsers too...

this condition doesn't work, even in canPlayType() supported browsers...

Comment: Sorry, left an extra parantheses in there. Check out the demo in different browsers, you should get an alert with your compatability.